# UNIX Shell: Code in the else part doesn't execute however the condition is checked

Tags: file, if-statement, unix, exists, is-empty

I have a  problem that when the file exists but is empty, i don't have a message " Le fichier file_name.txt est vide " , i get this message "Le fichier file_name.txt n'existe pas".

The code is below  :

```
if [[ -f ${rep_import}/file_name.txt && -s ${rep_import}/file_name.txt ]];then

    ecrit_trace "Le fichier file_name.txt existe et non vide "

elif [[ ! -f ${rep_import}/file_name.txt ]];then

    ecrit_trace "Le fichier file_name.txt n'existe pas "

else
   ecrit_trace "Le fichier file_name.txt est vide"

fi
```

Comment: When asking a code related question, it's always important to add a tag for the specific language you're using.  You've added a lot of totally meaningless tags and left off the single most important one. You'll stand a better chance of getting help  if you [edit] your post to correct that issue.

Comment: In the 2nd condition you have `{rep_import}` without the leading `$`.

Comment: The `$` has been added after an edit of your question. Did it change (maybe solve) the working of your code ?